# how to get specific <dd> tag content in httpresponse using jsoup

Tags: android

By using jsoup getting  tag content in httpresponse but in my httpresponse having number of  tags so here i want specific  tag and want to display it in a textview.here my question is how can i get specific  tag data in httpresponse using jsoup.
**code to get  tags in httpresponse**

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(result);

        Elements nodes = document.getElementsByTag("dd");
        System.out.println(nodes);
```

here posting logs

```
    09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866):  <b>DU06BFZ</b>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866):  TOYOTA / COROLLA VERSO
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866):  SILVER
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.836: I/System.out(866):  NMTEA16R60R017458
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866):  01/03/2006
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866):  Diesel
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.846: I/System.out(866):  <b>15/03/2013</b>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866):  67,885 Miles
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866):  435294573022
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866):  16/03/2014
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.856: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.878: I/System.out(866):  <b>DU06BFZ</b>
09-13 12:18:11.878: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.878: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.878: I/System.out(866):  TOYOTA / COROLLA VERSO
09-13 12:18:11.878: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.878: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.886: I/System.out(866):  SILVER
09-13 12:18:11.886: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.886: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.886: I/System.out(866):  NMTEA16R60R017458
09-13 12:18:11.886: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  01/03/2006
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  Diesel
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  <b>27/02/2009</b>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  29,896 Miles
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  211768059007
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  HOLDCROFT RENAULT
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.896: I/System.out(866):  3872B3
09-13 12:18:11.906: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.916: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.916: I/System.out(866):  01782214371
09-13 12:18:11.916: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.916: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.926: I/System.out(866):  IV
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866):  01/03/2010
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866):  <b>25/02/2010</b>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.937: I/System.out(866):  39,263 Miles
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866):  103776850049
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866):  PINKSTONES TOYOTA
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866):  1ALW35
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866):  01782599111
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.946: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866):  IV
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866):  01/03/2011
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866):  <b>17/03/2011</b>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866):  48,957 Miles
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866):  145016871496
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.956: I/System.out(866):  HOLDCROFT NISSAN
09-13 12:18:11.966: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.966: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.966: I/System.out(866):  49025
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866):  01782204040
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866):  IV
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866):  16/03/2012
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866):  <b>03/03/2012</b>
09-13 12:18:11.979: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866):  59,416 Miles
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866):  977003962078
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866):  PINKSTONES TOYOTA
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866):  1ALW35
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866):  01782599111
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866):  IV
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.989: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866):  16/03/2013
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866):  <b>15/03/2013</b>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866):  67,885 Miles
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): </dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): <dd>
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866):  435294573022
09-13 12:18:11.997: I/System.out(866): </dd>
```

Comment: can i ask from where you called service..? means you use your own web-service or getting data from any other web-service..??

Comment: own.......................

Comment: so you just need to modify your web-service and put specific tag in your jsop response so you can get better result.... for example instead of <dd>TOYOTO</dd> <dd>SILVER</dd> you may use <model>TOYOTO</model> <color>SILVER</color> <date>16/03/2013</date>.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will print all your  tags

```
public void xmlParse(String result) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        Log.i("String", "going in xml parse");
        boolean demoflag = false;

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(result));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("dd")) {
                    demoflag = true;
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                if (demoflag) {
                    Log.i("dd", "" + xpp.getText().trim());
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("country")) {
                    demoflag = false;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    }
```